# Try to apply css/style for parent tag on jquery toggle()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle the parent `<li>` and `<button>` styles.

Here my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn-comments").click(function(){
            $(this).css("border","none");
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
            $(".deal-comment-box").slideToggle(function() {

            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="comment-tools">
<ul>
    <li>views:<span class="count">10,500</span></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-share">Share</button></li>
    <li><button type="button"  class="btn-flag">Flag</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-comments">Comments</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-edit">edit</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-edit">remove</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="comment-box">
    <h3>All Comments (12)</h3>
</div>
 <div class="comment-tools">
<ul>
    <li>views:<span class="count">10,500</span></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-share">Share</button></li>
    <li><button type="button"  class="btn-flag">Flag</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-comments">Comments</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-edit">edit</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn-edit">remove</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="comment-box">
    <h3>All Comments (12)</h3>
</div>
```

The above section will repeat for n times.
clicking on comments button in `<li>` below comment box `<div>` will expand and i am trying remove the button border and giving some background for `<li>` in toggle mode.

Note: I need to toggle the button border and parent "selected" class too.

Could you please any say what mistake i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a .deal-comment-box in your markup or a .selected class, but you didn't include the css, so I assume that's there somewhere.

**EDIT:**

Check out the ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dWZq/)*** that utilizes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".btn-comments").click(function(){

            $(this)
                .toggleClass("button-clicked")   
                .parent().toggleClass("selected")
                .parent().next().toggle();

        });

    });
</script>
```

Someone may be able to optimize this but, at least it works for what your markup is.

Comment: border and selected class need to toggle and next() function not working suppose i remove the next() then all .comment-box class div's are expanded

Comment: @Elankeeran Where's the call to `next()` in your posted code?

Comment: Updated [working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dWZq/) to be a little more optimized.

Comment: Definitely a better solution than mine - should've remembered `toggleClass`! +1

Comment: Yea, it's a cool method, I like it. Also, it let's you keep your css and js separate. I hate debugging css and realizing that I styled it via css() in my jQuery file.

Comment: @Scott I have update my HTML I have problem here my comment box not next element for comment button.

Comment: @Elankeeran - Tell what exactly you are trying to do here. The .deal-comment-box class doesn't exist in your markup. Are you trying to hide/show the .comment-box div or the .comment-tools div upon button click?

Comment: @scott onclick "btn-comments" need to show "comment-box" and I need to changes the border to none for "btn-comments" and parent tag <li> need to apply one class.

Comment: @Elankeeran - Just add another .parent() via my [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dWZq/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If `border` and `selected` class need to toggle then you should hook a `toggle()` event handler on the button instead of `click()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-comments").toggle(function(){
        $(this).css("border","none");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        $(".deal-comment-box").slideToggle();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css("border","<set-it-back-to-original>");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
        $(".deal-comment-box").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: problem here I have n number of .deal-comment-box class for comment boxes and in this code opening all boxes